# Why does TeX not have a proper Content Management System?

Tags: tex-general

I am wondering why the Tex community does not have some sort of central Content Management System for version control and bug tracking, say, at CTAN. This community is surely large and mature enough for such an infrastructure, see TX.SX. It is embracing new technology when useful, see, again, TX.SX, or LuaTeX.

I am aware that some packages use such CMS'. I also know that MiKTeX does have a bug tracker at sourceforge, while TexLive does not. Wouldn't it be great if these forces were to be joined?

#### Background

I have mixed experiences with bug reporting via personal email. Heiko Oberdiek was very responsive, providing a new version of `hyperref`. On the other hand, I have a bug report for `refcheck`, but the email address of the maintainer is dead (host does not resolve). Now I have this neat MWE here, and nowhere to post it.

Comment: I think you mean something other than CMS, which is what is used to drive websites using database back-ends

Comment: @JosephWright Your connotation is the most widespread, but quoting Wikipedia: "A content management system (CMS)is a computer program that allows publishing, editing and modifying content as well as maintenance from a central interface. Such systems of content management provide procedures to manage workflow in a collaborative environment." What other term would you suggest?

Comment: I think that definition is self-conflicting. Central and collaborative concepts have changed after Bitkeeper and Git. Probably Wikipedia needs updating. But anyway this kind of emerging terminology is not a matter of science and you would get probably more help if you use the common terms.

Comment: Do you think there's a correct answer? I have doubts. It looks like a topic which can be talked about, but rather not on a Q&A site. There are ways, since we can work with TeX like with other programming languages, but who could ever answer the question for TeX as a whole? I guess the question can be closed as it leads to talks but not to an answer.

Comment: Isn't CTAN really a surprisingly tiny collection of individual volunteers? Do you mean package authors should submit their packages to 'CTAN' which would then be responsible for maintenance of all issues and bugs? Or that 'CTAN' could arbitrarily decide packages were 'unmaintained' and 'fix' bugs as they saw fit? IIRC, there is a process for getting a package declared 'unmaintained', but it is a slow and deliberately conservative process. Finally, why can't you post your `refcount` issue here; if it gets fixed, what's to stop you from creating `refcountx`.  Heiko Oberdiek has done this b4 too.

Comment: @jon: Please write such words out: “b4” means “before” I guess. You should not forget, that a lot users are not native English speakers with different levels of language knowledge.

Comment: @mafp: Also I think you mean [Wikipedia: Revision control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control). And this was John Wright relating to, I believe.

Comment: @percusse But what is the common term? No, I don't mean just a RCS, but that would be a start.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz I hope there is an answer. I am surely not the first asking about a RCS and a bug tracking system, say, and for some reason the answer was negative. I am intersted in those reasons.

Comment: They go mostly under the name of *version control system*, *revision control system* and it should be enough since Git handles Linux kernel. You might not need more than that anyway.

Comment: @jon No, I mean package authors would still be responsible for the bugs reported against their packages. You said yourself that CTAN decides about the maintanance status, so when enough bugs and patches crop up without action of the package maintainer, it is at least a sign that the package might need a new maintainer, or the package should be forked. I mean, the details were to be discussed, but lots of other projects get it done, too. Regarding the `refcheck` bug, see [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/2625/21591).

Comment: @percusse RCS is just one part, bug management another, ...

Comment: But bug management is truly distributed, every package owner corrects and uploads to CTAN. What exactly is it that you have in mind?

Comment: @mafp -- sure.  What you describe in your comment is basically what happens (I think), though it is usually wiser to post to `comp.text.tex` to bring inactivity/etc. to the attention of the CTAN people.  The process is slow, however, and that is by design. And of course forking is always permitted, even if it is not always advisable.  What H. Oberdiek does (e.g., `pdfcolparallel`) is warn that his package will become obsolete if the original package author fixes the clear bugs in his package.  That seems sensible to me.

Comment: @Speravir -- the 'b4' is because i had exactly zero characters left to write with.  I'm not twelve.

Comment: @jon: Oh, sorry! I didn’t think of this possible cause.

Comment: I think there is an intristic value in the decentralized nature of TeX. See e.g. Python `pip` and Ruby `gem` (and more); they work in similar ways and this has a clearly positive effect on the community around those languages. That said, I do think it's nice that packages are starting to pop up on Github, because my personal opinion is that a VCS combined with a proper issue tracker is more managable than bug report emails.

Comment: @You The comparison to python is quite fitting. But even python.org has an issue tracker at bugs.python.org, and a RCS via mercury. I'm not lobbying for a completely central solution, but having a core that is maintained with modern tools.

Comment: But the python.bugs.org tracker is for the core Python interpreter and packages, no? Granted, the core LaTeX packages don't have anything similar, but they're pretty stable and bug-free AFAIK and I feel that it should be the decision of the maintainers anyway.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to get at is that a) as a package maintainer, you may not want to outsource VCS/issue tracking (if you do; Github), b) as a core maintainer, you may not want to handle bug reports regarding packages you don't maintain and c) as a user, you'd want your bug report to be looked at as opposed to being stuck in an issue tracker which could be the wrong one or not frequented by the maintainer.

Comment: It's worth noting here that the LaTeX Project issue tracker (for kernel/required/tools bugs) does get some reports for other packages, and we have to close them. As @You says, this is not ideal for users as they don't actually get a result.

Comment: @You Ad a) Of course a bug tracker at CTAN would be opt-in, so if you want to run your own (why?), you could do so. Ad b) As Joseph points out, this is already happening right now. Ad c) True. But compare that to the situation right now, where you don't even know whether your bug report has made it through the internets. Plus, even a bug tracker that a maintainer ignores (why, when he opted in?) has some value, because other users could find the issue via google, interested people might comment, or even add a patch...

Comment: I mean, is it really that hard to see some advantages in that? Why do other communities like KDE run such infrastructure (it is completely opt-in)? I bet quite a few package maintainers would use such a system.

Comment: @Speravir -- no problem.  In all honesty I probably would've upvoted your comment if it hadn't been in response to mine....

Answer (score 7):

Well, it might be great but one thing is commonly forgotten: There are people needed to maintain everything and keep it running. The installation of a system is just a tiny part of the whole, it requires continous effort and a lot of time to install patches and take care of the server hardware. Most of the work around TeX is done by unpaid volunteers who spend their free time to work for the TeX community.

A version control and bugtracking system would be a nice thing for sure, but there are IMHO a few reasons that speak against:

1. TeX code is ASCII, there are almost no binaries which require code storage. Old TeX Live DVDs contain older package versions if needed.
2. If a package author dies or is just unavailable a version control/bug tracking system won't help much unless someone feels himself responsible to maintain the package and fix the bug.
3. The man and systems to operate such a thing is significant.

If you feel however capable to set up **and** maintain such a system for CTAN, start it! Great things often come from the hands of a single or just a few persons, see the [CTAN history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CTAN) in Wikipedia.

Comment: Ad 1: So is the GNOME code. Ad 2: Reported bugs could be found by other people having the same problem. You can also be sure to actually have reported your bug, and your email did not just ended up in the spam filter of a maintainer. Ad 3: I agree, but there are already several such systems for individual packages, and for MiKTeX. A central system might not be much more work.

Comment: None of the three points differentiate TeX from any other open source software collection. 1. Version control systems store source, not binaries. 2. No bug fixes itself, someone has to do it. 3. And yes, that's a significant service but the software for it exists: TeX needs nothing that github or bitbucket don't already provide. TeX is special, but not _that_ special.

Answer (score 6):

Many individual packages have their bug tracking system, for example, http://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/projects/tex4ht/.  TeX and friends is a huge collection (or rather collections, if you count each distribution) of code from many different independent sources, mostly volunteers.  It is an ecosystem rather than a project.  Thus we probably will never have a uniform management system - which is probably a good thing anyway.